# Objective c #import not linking to .h file

Tags: objective-c

i am new to objective c programming and programming in general.

i am trying to find out how to add a subclass into a project.

i have two separate Xcode projects on my desktop in a single folder.

The Shapes [Folder] houses the two project folders: Rectangle Project & Square Project

-- Rectangle Project consists of:

```
`Rectangle.h` [interface]

`Rectangle.m` [implementation]

`Rectangle Project.m` [main]

@interface Rectangle : NSObject
```

-- Square Project consists of:

```
`Square.h` [interface]

`Square.m` [implementation]

`Square Project.m` [main]

@interface Square : Rectangle
```

I want to import the rectangle.h file from the rectangle project into the square project in the square.h file.

In my Square.h file I am adding the following:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"

@interface Square : Rectangle
```

...I keep getting the error message: 
    `Rectangle: No such file or directory`.

How do I get objective c to recongnize the file?

I hope i'm making sense...

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need the ".h":

```
#import "Rectangle.h"
```

just like:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. actually that was a typo here. i originally had the #import "Rectangle.h" in the header. i have also tried using @class Rectangle.h; in the header and moving the #import "Rectangle.h" file into the Sqaure.m file... it still won't link up... do i need to open a new objective c class from with in a project in Xcode to get classes to link... i really appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: @michael: Is Rectangle.h actually in your project? (Right click it and Show in Finder to see if it's in the right directory.) Also, check to see if it's listed in the Compile Sources section of Build Phases.

Comment: Thanks Evan. Read through the Xcode Project management Guide. In Xcode I clicked on the Action drop down menu and chose add --> existing file. This seemed to have fixed the problem. It added the whole project into my Xcode Source Files. I didn't think I had to import them into Xcode to link them. i just thought I could link a file via import:                                               #import "SuperClass.h"                                        @interface Subclass : Superclass                                      Is this the wrong understanding?